# Python: Compare & Count Dictionary Structures Across Thousands of Dictionaries/XMLs/JSON

Tags: python, json, xml, dictionary, elementtree

I'm parsing many thousands of XML files into dictionaries, and storing their structures in JSON.

They have much the same structure, but there is an unknown number of different tag-naming schemes. A variety of different abbreviations exist for naming tags within these thousands of files.

I need to find out how many different tags exist to describe each piece of information, to parse all of them correctly.

To do so, I want to create one master dictionary of the XMLs/dictionaries that includes all variations on tag names, and preferably their counts within the thousands of XMLs/dictionaries.

Here's a small sample of one of the dictionaries:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Ts": {},
        "PeriodEndDt": {},
        "PreparedBy": {
            "PreparerID": {},
            "PreparerFirmName": {
                "BusinessNameLine1Txt": {}
            },
            "PreparerAddress": {
                "AddLn1Txt": {},
                "CityName": {},
                "StateAbbreviationCd": {},
                "ZIPCd": {}
            }
        },
        "FormTypeCd": {},
        "PeriodBeginDt": {},
        "Filer": {
            "UniqueID": {},
            "BusinessName": {
                "BusinessNameLine1Txt": {}
            },
            "BusinessNameControlTxt": {},
            "PhoneNum": {},
            "USAddress": {
                "AddressLine1Txt": {},
                "CityNm": {},
                "StateAbbreviationCd": {},
                "ZIPCd": {}
            }
        },

        "FormData": {
            "FormCodeType": {
                "BizType": {},
                "AssetsAtEOY": {},
                "AccountingMethod": {},
                "RevenueAndExpenses": {
                    "ScheduleBNotReqd": {},
                    "DivsRevAndExpenses": {},
                    "DivsNetInvstIncomeAmt": {},
                    "NetGainSaleAstRevAndExpnssAmt": {},
                    "RevsOvrExpenses": {},
                    "NetInvestmentIncomeAmt": {}
                },
                "BalanceSheetGroup": {
                    "CashInvstBOYAmt": {},
                    "CashInvstEOYAmt": {},
                    "CashInvstEOYFMVAmt": {},
                    "OtherInvestmentsBOYAmt": {},
                    "OtherInvestmentsEOYAmt": {},
                    "CapitalStockEOYAmt": {},
                    "TotalLiabilitiesNetAstEOYAmt": {}
                },
                "ChangeNetAssetsFundGroup": {
                    "NetAssettFundBalancesBOYAmt": {},
                    "ExcessRevExpensesAmt": {},
                    "OtherIncreasesAmt": {},
                    "SubtotalAmt": {},
                    "OtherDecreasesAmt": {},
                    "TotNetAstOrFundBalancesEOYAmt": {}
                },
                "CapGainsLossTxInvstIncmDetail": {
                    "CapGainsLossTxInvstIncmGrp": {
                        "PropertyDesc": {},
                        "HowAcquiredCd": {},
                        "GrossSalesPriceAmt": {},
                        "GainOrLossAmt": {},
                        "GainsMinusExcessOrLossesAmt": {}
                    },
                    "StatementsRegardingActyGrp": {
                        "LegislativePoliticalActyInd": {},
                        "MoreThan100SpentInd": {}
                    },
                    "PhoneNum": {},
                    "LocationOfBooksUSAddress": {
                        "AddressLine1Txt": {},
                        "CityNm": {},
                        "StateAbbreviationCd": {},
                        "ZIPCd": {}
                    },
                    "CorporateDirectorsGrp": {
                        "DirectorsGrp": {
                            "PersonNm": {},
                            "USAddress": {
                                "AddressLine1Txt": {},
                                "CityNm": {},
                                "StateAbbreviationCd": {},
                                "ZIPCd": {}
                            },
                            "EmpPrograms": {
                                "EmployeeBenefitGroupNum": {},
                                "GroupType": {
                                    "GroupElement": {},
                                    "GroupCharacter": {
                                        "GroupNames": {}
                                    }
                                }

                            },
                            "EmpOffice1": {},
                            "EmpOffice2": {},
                            "EmpOffice3": {},
                            "EmpOffice4": {}
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to create the dictionaries/JSON in the first place is like  this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

strip_ns = lambda xx: str(xx).split('}', 1)[1]
tree = ET.parse('xmlpath.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


tierdict = {}
for tier1 in root:
    tier1var = strip_ns(tier1.tag)
    tierdict[tier1var] = {}
    for tier2 in tier1:
        tier2var = strip_ns(tier2.tag)
        tierdict[tier1var][tier2var] = {}
        for tier3 in tier2:
            tier3var = strip_ns(tier3.tag)
            tierdict[tier1var][tier2var][tier3var] = {}
            for tier4 in tier3:
                tier4var = strip_ns(tier4.tag)
                tierdict[tier1var][tier2var][tier3var][tier4var] = {}
```

The output I'd want to see is something like:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Header.Count": 5672,
        "Ts": {
            "Ts.Count": 3365
            },
        "Ss": {
            "Ss.Count": 2328
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do a recursive search of the elements you want as defined below:

```
def get_elements(json_entry, child_elements=[]):

     if not child_elements:
         return json_entry

     el, other_children = child_elements[0], child_elements[1:]

     children = el.getchildren()
     rec = json_entry.get(el.tag)
     if not children:
         json_entry[el.tag] = {"Count": rec.get("Count",0)+1 if rec else 1}

     else:
         json_entry[el.tag] = {"Count": rec.get("Count",0) if rec else 1,
                                    **get_elements({}, children)}

     return get_elements(json_entry, other_children)
```

This way, you can just pass the root element of your xml:

```
from lxml import etree

with open("myxml.xml", "r") as fh:
    tree = etree.parse(fh)

root = tree.getroot()

root_children = root.getchildren()

child_recs = get_elements({}, root_children)

{'tagOne': {'Count': 1}, 'tagTwo': {'Count': 1, 'tagThree': {'Count': 1}, 'tagFour': {'Count': 1, 'tagFive': {'Count': 1}}}}
```

If you want to wrap your root element around it, do it like so:

```
master_lookup = {root.tag: {"Count": 1, **child_recs}}
```

This can be easily extended to a `for` loop through many files

```
master_lookup = {}

for file in os.walk(path):
    with open(file) as fh:
        tree = etree.parse(fh)

    root = tree.getroot()
    root_entry = master_lookup.get(root.tag, {"Count": 0})
    root_children = root.getchildren()

    root_count = root_entry.pop("Count")

    master_lookup[root.tag] = {"Count": root_count, **get_elements({**root_entry}, root_children)}
```

Something to that effect

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply!

Where are you getting `getchildren()` from? Every place I've seen it, it's not part of Python 3.

Comment: `getchildren` is a function of an `Element` (part of the `etree`). So each `Element` in a tree has that method. It will return a list of all of the child elements (empty list, if there aren't any) which is why the unpack doesn't throw an `IndexError`

Comment: I'm running this in Python 3.6, if that matters

Comment: Thanks, again, for your help here. I'm still trying to make this work. For now, I must be doing something wrong with the loop, such that the `master_lookup`'s final value seems to be derived from only a single file, with all counts = 1, and seeming a number of distinct fields from various of the files not included in that dict.

Comment: So for the loop of the files, it's not 100% correct. I'll make an edit

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this! I'm still not quite there.
Some areas I'm working on: on the first run through the loop, after the first definition of `root_entry`, its value is `{'Count': 0}`. On subsequent runs, it seems to take the entire set of tags from an XML file as its value, but then starts with that same `{'Count': 0}` as its first kv pair.

On the other hand, the value for `root_children` in the main loop seems to be exactly what I'd expect, each time: The couple of tags nested just under the root. And overall, the output of `master_lookup` is the same as before.

Comment: Doing a little more work on this, `get_elements` seems to be doing a job of creating a dictionary for any 1 file, with proper nesting and a count of 1. The question now is how to make the outer loop called by `master_lookup` count with comparison/addition, since what it's doing is only populating the dict with the last file that ran.

Comment: Sorry for all the headache, recursion is definitely what you want. The loop should be grabbing the `root.tag` from the current dict. If there is one, it `pop`s the count, that way it can just dump the rest into the recursion function. Looks like the second `rec.get("Count", 0)` needs a `+1` otherwise there is no addition, as you've stated